# Component not rendered with Vue compat

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to switch my Vue app from Vue 2 to Vue 3, using the [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html) in order to do this progressively. I've followed points 1 to 3, but when starting my application it seems like my root component is not rendered correctly.

Here is the file initializing the app:

```js
import Vue, {configureCompat} from "vue";

configureCompat({
    "MODE": 2
});

new Vue({
    "template": "<h1>Hello world!</h1>",
    mounted() {
        console.log("Mounted");
    }
}).$mount("#app");
```

And the output HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app" data-v-app>
        <!---->
    </div>
</body>
```

What is strange is that I can see the `Mounted` log in the console, and if I change `import Vue from "vue";` by `import Vue from "@vue/compat"` it works, but as I understand it this should not be needed since I configured an alias in my Webpack config to make `vue` point to `@vue/compat`:

```js
process.env.BABEL_ENV = "renderer";

const path = require("path");
const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require("vue-loader");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const {dependencies} = require("./package.json");

// List of Node modules to include in webpack bundle.
// Required for specific packages like Vue UI libraries that provide pure `.vue` files that need compiling.
const WHITE_LISTED_MODULES = [
    "vue"
];

const rendererConfig = {
    "target": "electron-renderer",
    "mode": (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") ? "production" : "development",
    "entry": {
        "renderer": path.join(__dirname, "./src/renderer/index.js")
    },
    "output": {
        "globalObject": "this",
        "filename": "[name].js",
        "libraryTarget": "commonjs2",
        "path": path.join(__dirname, "./dist")
    },
    "externals": [
        ...Object.keys(dependencies || {}).filter((d) => !WHITE_LISTED_MODULES.includes(d))
    ],
    "resolve": {
        "alias": {
            "@": path.join(__dirname, "./src/renderer"),
            "vue": "@vue/compat"
        },
        "extensions": [".js", ".vue"]
    },
    "node": {
        "__dirname": process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
        "__filename": process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.vue$/,
                "use": {
                    "loader": "vue-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "compilerOptions": {
                            "compatConfig": {
                                "MODE": 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "plugins": [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            "filename": "index.html",
            "template": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/renderer/index.ejs"),
            "nodeModules": (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") ? false : path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules"),
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = rendererConfig;
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I also tried to remove the `@` alias but it does not change anything. It seems like the `vue` alias is kind of working because `configureCompat` is correctly defined, whereas it is undefined if I remove the `vue` alias.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fix was to change in `resolve.alias`:

```
"vue": "@vue/compat"
```

by:

```
"vue": "@vue/compat/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
```

Comment: Do you know why this worked?