# Vue compat migration Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

So I'm trying to migrate project from vue 2 to vue 3 but unfortuneltely I got a warning:

> Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".

But I can't use esm-bundler if I want to use vue/compat right?

Is there a solution to that problem?

Comment: Which browsers do you need `compat`? I know that IE is dead and not supported by Vue3. Are there some other browsers not being able to parse ESM by default? The ESM build should be enough nowadays IMO.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried it on chrome.

Comment: Why do you need `vue/compat`?

Comment: I have big project and it's hard to find all errors, so I wanted to help myself especially with https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/attribute-coercion.html

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196090/4003671):

Use `@vue/compat/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js`

Comment: if the question is a duplicate, flag it as such instead of writing an answer post.

Comment: I think this is a clearer question (and I landed on this one from Google first). Ideally I guess the other question would be marked as a duplicate of this? But the other question is the one with the answer.